# Change location in a javascript menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, categories

I need a script in Jquery for select a sub-menu in another special javascript menu.Every sub-menu there are new content,and for this that I would like make an automatic switcher. Naturally in that page (Of the menu) there are some scripts embed:

functions.js -> [link text](http://pastebin.com/sVpMAFSj)

util.js -> [link text](http://pastebin.com/XCwtwfF7)

JSONREQUEST.js -> [link text](http://pastebin.com/tU4AFNi1)

category.js -> [link text](http://pastebin.com/0W6wRjNW)

I think that solution is in category.js, because there's a function named updatepage()

P.S: I can use also the 'function' of browser, javascript: "SCRIPT FOR SWITCH";

Images below:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: use pagination plugin on jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems actually similar to pagination using jquery/php/mysql.

i am considering it to be like jquery/php/mysql,

**Procedure**

When you click the number, it try to pull data from db using php and send it back to javascript. javascript will load the content on fixed area asynchronously. every thing number change produce called again.

here are some quick tutorials

- [Pagination with jQuery, MySQL and PHP.](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html)
- [How To Create A Simple Pagination System Using jQuery, PHP and mySQL](http://blarnee.com/wp/how-to-create-a-simple-pagination-system-using-jquery-php-and-mysql/)
- [Ajax Pagination With Jquery,PHP,Mysql](http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/04/20/ajax-pagination-with-jqueryphpmysql/)

Comment: Finally is not possible to make an external script for switch this? :(

Comment: when you say external means, script hosted in other location. if yes then ya you can do that.